# Tabs component in javascript class should be reusable

Tags: javascript

I have a component that should be reusable within a page. And it should be called only when in view.

I've added an extra class function outside `class Tabs` which is called `class Pagination`.

this class is not within class Tabs which is breaking the component if reused within the page (multiple times).

Would anyone help me to move the class Pagination inside Tabs? My goal is having a unique class, so I can reuse the component multiple times and only when is in view. I really hope it makes sense,

here you have a [Pen demo](https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/mdqKXLq), as you can see the pagination is not in the right constuctor. I brake the function everytime I try to move it.

```js
class Pagination {
  constructor(tabComponent, prevBtnId, nextBtnId) {
    this.arrayUtils = new ArrayUtils();
    this.tabComponent = tabComponent;
    this.prevBtn = document.querySelector(prevBtnId);
    this.nextBtn = document.querySelector(nextBtnId);

    // listen to tabComponents newly created Toggle event
    // in which we wanna make sure to disable Btns or something..
    this.tabComponent.onTabsToggle((tabs, tabIndex) => {
      this.applyPaginationRules(tabs, tabIndex);
    });
  }

  setDisabled(btn, value) {
    if (value) {
      btn.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
    } else {
      btn.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
  }

  applyPaginationRules(tabs, newActiveIndex) {
    const nextBtnDisabled = newActiveIndex === tabs.length - 1;
    const prevBtnDisabled = newActiveIndex === 0;

    this.setDisabled(this.nextBtn, nextBtnDisabled);
    this.setDisabled(this.prevBtn, prevBtnDisabled);
  }

  paginate(btn, action) {
    const block = btn.closest(".tabs-block");
    const panels = block.querySelectorAll(".panel");
    const tabs = block.querySelectorAll(".tab-wrapper > li > button");
    const activeIndex = Array.from(tabs).findIndex(
      (t) => t.getAttribute("data-open") === "true"
    );

    if (tabs.length < 2) {
      console.log("0 OR 1 tabs to toggle so no action.");
      return;
    }

    var newActiveIndex;

    if (action === "next") {
      newActiveIndex = this.arrayUtils.nextIndex(activeIndex, tabs);
    } else if (action === "prev") {
      newActiveIndex = this.arrayUtils.previousIndex(activeIndex, tabs);
    } else {
      throw "Invalid toggle action " + action;
    }

    // enable / disable next and previous btns..
    this.applyPaginationRules(tabs, newActiveIndex);

    this.tabComponent.toggleTabs(tabs[newActiveIndex], panels);
  }

  addPaginationListener(btn, action) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      this.paginate(btn, action);
    });
  }

  init() {
    this.addPaginationListener(this.prevBtn, "prev");
    this.addPaginationListener(this.nextBtn, "next");

    // disable prev button on beggining since we start at 0..
    this.setDisabled(this.prevBtn, true);
  }
}

class ArrayUtils {
  // getting next index in array
  nextIndex(currentIndex, array) {
    // if 0 OR 1 elements, index stays the same..
    if (array.length < 2) return currentIndex;

    // if possible increment.
    if (currentIndex < array.length - 1) {
      return currentIndex + 1;
    }

    // if index would exceed array size go to start.
    return 0;
  }

  // getting previous INdex in array:
  previousIndex(currentIndex, array) {
    // if 0 OR 1 elements, index stays the same..
    if (array.length < 2) return currentIndex;

    // if possible decrement!
    if (currentIndex > 0) {
      return currentIndex - 1;
    }

    // start at the end of array when end is reached ofc.
    return array.length - 1;
  }
}

class Tabs {
  constructor() {
    this.tabsBlocks = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs-block");
    this.onToggleHandlers = [];
  }

  onTabsToggle(fn) {
    this.onToggleHandlers.push(fn);
  }

  emitTabsToggle(tabs, tabIndex) {
    this.onToggleHandlers.forEach((fn) => fn(tabs, tabIndex));
  }

  init() {
    if (this.tabsBlocks.length > 0) {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.tabsBlocks, (tabBlock, index) => {
        const tabContainer = tabBlock.querySelector(".tab-wrapper");
        const tabs = tabBlock.querySelectorAll(".tab-wrapper li button");
        const panels = tabBlock.querySelectorAll(".panel");

        tabContainer.setAttribute("role", "tablist");

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(tabs, (tab, tabIndex) => {
          if (tab.dataset.open === "true") this.toggleTabs(tab, panels);

          tab.setAttribute("role", "tab");
          tab.setAttribute(
            "aria-controls",
            `panel-${tab.dataset.target}-block-${index + 1}`
          );

          const associatedPanel = tabBlock.querySelector(
            `[data-panel="${tab.dataset.target}"]`
          );

          if (associatedPanel !== null) {
            associatedPanel.id = `panel-${tab.dataset.target}-block-${
              index + 1
            }`;
            tab.id = `tab-${tab.dataset.target}-block-${index + 1}`;
          }

          tab.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.toggleTabs(tab, panels);

            this.emitTabsToggle(tabs, tabIndex);
          });
        });

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(panels, (panel) => {
          const associatedTab = tabBlock.querySelector(
            `[data-target="${panel.dataset.panel}"]`
          );

          panel.setAttribute("role", "tabpanel");
          panel.setAttribute("aria-labelledby", `${associatedTab.id}`);
        });
      });
    }
  }

  toggleTabs = (currentTab, panels) => {
    const tabs = currentTab.closest(".tabs-block").querySelectorAll("button");

    const target = currentTab.dataset.target;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(tabs, (tab) => {
      if (tab.dataset.target !== target) {
        tab.classList.remove("is-active");
        tab.setAttribute("data-open", "false");
        tab.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
      }
    });

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(panels, (panel) => {
      if (panel.dataset.panel !== target) {
        panel.classList.remove("is-active");
      } else {
        panel.classList.add("is-active");
      }
    });

    /// activate tab..
    currentTab.classList.add("is-active");
    currentTab.setAttribute("data-open", "true");
    currentTab.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
  };
}

const components = {
  Tabs: new Tabs()
};

components.Tabs.init(); 
// have the pagination more decoupled from tabs!
// it uses tabs component but you can remove it OR apply it to other
// classes like so more easily..
const prevBtnId = ".pagination-prev";
const nextBtnId = ".pagination-next";
const pagination = new Pagination(components.Tabs, prevBtnId, nextBtnId);
pagination.init();
```

```css
.tabs-block {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.tabs-block .tab-wrapper li {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  text-align: center;
}
.tabs-block .tab-wrapper li button {
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: rem(20px);
}
.tabs-block .tab-wrapper li button.is-active {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.tabs-block .panel {
  display: none;
}
.tabs-block .panel.is-active {
  display: block;
}

.is-active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="tabs-block">
  <ul class="tab-wrapper">
    <li><button data-target="1" data-open="true">Tab title 1</button></li>
    <li><button data-target="2">Tab title 2</button></li>
    <li><button data-target="3">Tab title 3</button></li>

  </ul>
  <div class="panel-wrapper">
    <div data-panel="1" class="panel">
      <p>Panel 1 content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-panel="2" class="panel">
      <p>Panel 2 content</p>
    </div>
    <div data-panel="3" class="panel">
      <p>Panel 3 content</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="buttonPrev pagination-prev">
    << Prev</button>
      <button class="buttonNext pagination-next">Next >></button>
</section>
```